# How to build zeppelin 0.8.0 with spark 2.3.2 inbuilt

Tags: apache-zeppelin, apache-spark-2.3

I want build zeppelin 0.8.0 with spark 2.3.2 inbuilt and run it against the same version of spark running not locally without setting SPARK_HOME so that I do not require to have a SPARK installation in the zeppelin node. I have tried the build options given in the document https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/setup/basics/how_to_build.html but it fails the build trying to build for scala 2.10.

Is this even possible with the 0.8.0 version?

So you can build the 0.8.1-snapshot with spark 2.3.2. But however you cannot connect to an external spark node using the inbuilt spark binaries without giving a seperate spark installation using SPARK_HOME.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge code from this [pull request](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/3206) and then the spark-2.3 profile will build with spark 2.3.2 and won't fail with scala 2.10 error.

Or wait for 0.8.1 ([first candidate was tagged today!](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/releases/tag/v0.8.1-rc1))

Comment: I got the build through by using the 0.8.1 candidate tag but now I am facing an issue where I can't use the inbuilt spark binaries to talk with a non-local spark node.

Comment: I tracked the change to the function setupPropertiesForSparkR in SparkInterpreterLauncher.java which was not there in the previous builds